# Calendar vs Sharepoint-Calendar

Tags: discussion, tags

What is the difference between the [sharepoint-calendar](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint-calendar) tag and [calendar](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar) tag?  Should there be an alias?  Or should one be retired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint has a minimum of 2 different calendars by default.

1. SharePoint calendar
2. Outlook calendar

Besides that there exist multiple different 3rd party calendars out there. So this is to differentiate from the SharePoint calendar and other calendars.

Comment: Also - SharePoint calendars can be 'Connected to Outlook' calendars or subscribed to as an RSS feed, which are not sharepoint-calendars.  I vote keep the 2 seperate tags.